# How to check the status of a storyboard?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

How would I check the status of a storyboard?

Example:

```
if (storyboard.Completed += true) // ???
{
}
```

(This code *does not* work, for obvious reasons.)

Comment: Back-ticks for inline code; New paragraph and 4-space indent for code blocks (select code block and press the "{}" button in the editor). Happy SO'ing.

Comment: Thanks! I always wondered why the code editor hated me...

Comment: just wanted to check in to see if the below answers your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just hook the `Completed` event and when your code runs in there, the storyboard will have been completed. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed(VS.95).aspx#Y565

Comment: How would I use this? (for instance,                 storyboard.Completed += Completed;)

Comment: That's right. Check out the sample on http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/Silverlight/SampleBrowser/index.htm#/?sref=change_targetname_2 (click the "View Sample Source Code" button and then the C# button that comes up on that page at the top).

Answer (score 4):

how about creating a boolean variable (e.g. IsCompleted) and set it to true in the Completed callback?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(storyboard.GetCurrentState() == ClockState.Active)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work.

```html
            Storyboard storyBoardPulse = this.FindResource("StoryboardMainIconPulse") as Storyboard;
            Storyboard.SetTarget(storyBoardPulse, this.imageIcon);

            if (storyBoardPulse.GetCurrentState() != ClockState.Active)
            {
                storyBoardPulse.Begin();
            }
```

gets back this **error:**

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
>
> HResult=-2146233079
>
> Message=Impossible to execute the action. the Storyboard specify not
>   applied to this object for interactive control.

Ao I make a very bloody workaround:

```html
private Boolean pulseOn;

private void operationsOfMaintenance_OperationExpired(Boolean state)
        {
            Storyboard storyBoardPulse = this.FindResource("StoryboardMainIconPulse") as Storyboard;
            Storyboard.SetTarget(storyBoardPulse, this.imageIcon);

            if (!state)
            {
                storyBoardPulse.Stop();
                storyBoardPulse.Remove();
                pulseOn = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if(!pulseOn)storyBoardPulse.Begin();
                pulseOn = true;
            }
        }
```

There's anyboody know why the first example gets an error!

thanks